# Limit sql query to only rows where aggregate of col = 0

Tags: sql

I'm looking at auction data in the following form:

```
product   auction_id   bid_value   is_winning_bid   reject_reason
iPhone    123          5           1                0
iPhone    123          3           0                1
iPhone    123          2           0                200
iPad      456          1           0                1
iPad      456          10          0                1
iPhone    789          2           0                200
iPhone    999          10          0                1
```

I want to count the number of auctions where one of the bids had a reject_reason = 200 and none of the bids has a is_winning_bid = 1, grouped by product.The data set is large so I don't want to have the output grouped by auction_id.

The table above should result in:

```
product   total_auctions   count_unfilled_auctions   count_unfilled_auctions_200

iPhone    3                2                         1
iPad      1                1                         0
```

Comment: What is the calculations for `count_unfilled_auctions` and `count_unfilled_auctions_404`?

Comment: Your question's subject doesn't fully match the description of what you are counting and the definitions of your output column names are fully obviously from your statement of the problem.

Comment: Auction 123 should be included in iPhone.total_auctions, but not iPhone.unfilled_auctions, correct?

Comment: Auction 123 should be included in iPhone.total_auctions, but not iPhone.unfilled_auctions. True

Comment: Apologies - the result table had a typo. The last column is count_unfilled_auctions_200. It is the count of auctions where the max(is_winning_bid) = 0 and one of the bids got a reject_reason = 200

Comment: It looks possible with a product-based query with three joined subqueries to count the qualifying auctions of each result type, the second and third sub-queries filtered to remove those with a winning bid - have I missed a complicating factor?

Comment: No that sounds right to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need two levels of aggregation, one at the auction level and one at the product level:

```
select product, count(*) as total_auctions,
       sum(1 - has_winning_bid) as unfulfilled_auctions,
       sum(case when cnt_reject_200 > 0 and has_winning_bid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as unfulfilled_auctions_200
from (select auction_id, product,
             max(is_winning_bid) as has_winning_bid,
             sum(case when reject_reason = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_reject_200
      from auctiondata ad
      group by auction_id, product
     ) ad
group by product;
```